# code requirement for cooktop gas hookup to be in another cabinet?

Tags: kitchens, code-compliance, gas, oven

The manual on my kitchen cooktop states:

> If a built-in wall oven is to be installed below this cooktop, the
>   grounded outlet and gas supply piping must be located in an adjacent
>   cabinet.

Is this a US code requirement? Or just a concession that there is no space for a gas hookup in the cabinet when a wall oven is installed in a base cabinet (since they go all the way back to the wall).

I want to move the gas line to inside the toe kick area of the cabinet with the oven and cooktop, as the 5" height there is more than enough space and is accessible when the oven is removed.

Comment: Most building codes (at least in the US) specify that you should follow all manufacturer's installation instructions. So despite what code says, following the instructions is usually the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's so that you can maintain easy access to the plug and gas valve if anything were to go wrong.

> "is accessible when the oven is removed"

You don't want to have to move the oven to shut off the gas.

Comment: Ok, I can see your point, but having to remove drawers or empty a cabinet to get to the shutoff doesn't seem easy either...

Comment: @user1663987 -- it's easier than removing a built-in oven!

Answer (score 0):

For Whirlpool ovens it says "For undercounter installation [under a gas cooktop], it is **recommended** that the junction box for oven be located in the adjacent right or left cabinet." [**emphasis** added] and then includes locations where a gas line can be located within the same cabinet as the oven.

So this must not be any countrywide code if manufacturers can give such widely varying instructions.